# SQL Server: Is it possible to cascade update a self referencing table?

Tags: sql-server

It would appear that, at least through management studio express, it is not possible to set a foreign key constraint that references the same table to do anything on update or delete.
I have a table where I would like to cascade updates to null if a row is removed.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to handle this situation with an [INSTEAD OF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521.aspx) DELETE trigger.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_IOD_YourTable ON YourTable
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE yt
        SET ChildForeignKey = NULL
        FROM deleted d
            INNER JOIN YourTable yt
                ON d.PrimaryKeyColumn = yt.ChildForeignKey

    DELETE FROM yt
        FROM deleted d
            INNER JOIN YourTable yt
                ON d.PrimaryKeyColumn = yt.PrimaryKeyColumn
END
```