# On update cascade for a self-referencing key - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ssms, cascade

I am trying to figure out how to perform on update cascade on a self-referencing temporal table using triggers. While I found that this post ([On delete cascade for self-referencing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228082/on-delete-cascade-for-self-referencing-table)) is the closest it can get to my answer, I had the below questions:

The Answer and the question seems incomplete in the post. Can you please tell me what is contained in `Deleted` table in the post? What is `id` in `Deleted` table and `Comments` table? Is it a primary key? What if primary key is a pair of columns? Also, I am not sure why is IDs inside the CTE IDs. Seems incorrect. I am not sure.

What would the on update cascade specific trigger look like if the table has other foreign key constraints?

I have the below table setup. Can you please help me create a trigger for it on update cascade on the foreign key FK_Son_Height_Weight?
I could use a surrogate key here but there are several tables that have foreign key reference to PK_Height_Weight. Is there a way to make sure I dont need a surrogate key?

(Note: the table has been modified for privacy reasons)

CREATE TABLE no.Man (

```
Height varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Weight varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Height_Weight PRIMARY KEY (Height, Weight),
CONSTRAINT FK_Weight FOREIGN KEY (Weight)
REFERENCES no.Human (Weight)
On Update Cascade,
Son_Height varchar (100) NOT NULL, 
Son_Weight varchar (50) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT FK_Son_Height_Weight FOREIGN KEY (Son_Height, Son_Weight) 
REFERENCES no.Man(Height,Weight)
On Update Cascade
)
```

Comment: The `Deleted` pseudo-table only exists inside the trigger - it contains the rows being deleted (in a `ON DELETE` trigger) - or the "old" rows before the `UPDATE` took place in a `ON UPDATE` trigger. It contains the exact same columns as the table the trigger is attached to

Comment: Can you please help me modify the query if there were other foreign key constraints in the table for on update cascade?

Comment: "What if primary key is a pair of columns?" - if you have many columns, lets say ID1, ID2, ID2 then, when deleting records, instead of `WHERE col IN( .... )` you would need an `INNER JOIN`. See ["Delete With INNER JOIN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-can-i-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server) examples.

Comment: "Also, I am not sure why is IDs inside the CTE" - if you are referring to `;WITH IDs as` then `IDs` in this case is just a name. It can be "Bob" or anything else.

Comment: "What would the on update cascade specific trigger look like if the table has other foreign key constraints?" - you would need more delete statements e.g. `DELETE FROM OtherTable .......` and then `DELETE FROM OtherTable2 .......` etc.

Comment: Alex - I dont want to delete as shown in the below query :- -- Delete from FK referenced table
    DELETE FROM OtherTable
    WHERE CommentID in (select ID from @deletions)

    --This delete comes last
    DELETE FROM Comments
    WHERE id in (select ID from @deletions); I want to update two referenced columns

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347903/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-cascade-update-a-self-referencing-table). Give it a try yourself an post your attempt. I will have a look at this afterwards.

Comment: You can't do an `update cascade` with a trigger because there is no way to match the rows from `inserted` to the ones in `deleted`. Unless you have a *second* unique constraint which doesn't change. `delete cascade` is no problem because you don't need to worry about what to update the values to, you just delete

Answer (score 0):

Since the table is a temporal table, only 'After Update' trigger can be used on it and not the 'Instead Of Update' trigger ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations?view=sql-server-ver15) for reference). I used the below solution for now to set stuff to null. This isnt a complete answer - yet trying to share with the community what I know.

```
CREATE or ALTER TRIGGER no.Weight_Height
ON no.Man
After UPDATE
AS
Set nocount on
IF ( UPDATE (Height) AND UPDATE (Weight) )
    ;With BA_DEL_Join as
    (
    select d.Height as d_Height, d.Weight as d_Weight, 
        d.Son_Height_Number as d_Son_Height_Num, d.Son_Weight as 
        d_Son_Weight, ba.Height as ba_Height, ba.Weight as ba_Weight, 
        ba.Son_Height_Number as ba_Son_Height_Num, ba.Son_Weight as 
        ba_Son_Weight 
    from deleted d
    inner join no.Man ba
    on d.Height = ba.Son_Height_Number and d.Weight = ba.Son_Weight
    )

    Update no.Man
    set Son_Height_Number = NULL, Son_Weight = NULL
    from BA_DEL_Join
    where d_Height = ba_Son_Height_Num and d_Weight = ba_Son_Weight
    Go
```

Even though this code mimics a cascading event - it does not enfore referential integrity.